# open port 21 in os x server 10.6 mac for FTP server

Tags: mac-osx

I am having the same problem. Where was this thread continued?
Actually I want to open port 21. The firewall in the mac  server is already off.The ftp server is enabled in this mac server. The NAT in the router is set accordingly to the internal IP of this MAC computer (OS X Server 10.6). However, whenever I try http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/ to check whether the port 21 is open or not, it still says that the port is closed.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/244451/open-port-21-in-os-x-server-10-6-mac-for-ftp-server).

Comment: And also [on non-SE sites](http://forums.macnn.com/92/networking/433260/open-port-21-ftp-mac-osx/), and [another](http://macosx.com/forums/mac-os-x-system-mac-software/317760-open-port-21-ftp-mac-osx-server-10-6-a.html).

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting:

On the mac - telnet or ftp to localhost on port 21.  If it returns something ftp is running thats good.  If it doesnt its a problem with the ftp server software.

From a computer on the same network telnet or ftp to the mac on port 21.  If it returns something thats good that means the firewall on the mac is indeed off.  If it doesnt that means its probably the ftp configuration on listening IP or the firewall on the mac.

from the outside telnet or ftp to the mac on port 21.  If it returns something thats good that means it should be all set.  If it doesnt and all the steps above are ok then it is your NAT.